# Match strings stored in variables using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, string-comparison

I am attempting to create a backup script that will move files that are older that 30 days, but I want to be able to exclude folders from the list

```
$a = "C:\\Temp\\Exclude\\test"
$b = "C:\\Temp\\Exclude"
```

if I run the following:

```
$a -match $b
```

Following [PowerShell Basics: Conditional Operators -Match -Like -Contains & -In -NotIn](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_conditional_operators.htm#Example_1_-Match):

```
$Guy ="Guy Thomas 1949"
$Guy -match "Th"
```

This returns `true`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say use wilcards and the like operator, it can save you a lot of head aches:

```
$a -like "$b*"
```

The match operator is using regex pattern and the path is having regex special characters in it (the escape characeter). If you still want to use -match - make sure to escape the string:

```
$a -match [regex]::escape($b)
```

This will work but keep in mind that it can match in the middle of the string, you can add the '^' anchor to tell the regex engine to match from the begining of the string:

```
$a -match ("^"+[regex]::escape($b))
```

Comment: the seconds and third one worked as long as I did $a[0] -match [regex]::escape($b[0]) and this now resolves as true $a[0] -match $b[0]  which makes no sense to me, when I check the properties they all say system.string.... thanks

Comment: You're indexing the string and get back the first character from each variable ('C').