# The specified wildcard pattern is not valid: '*warnings: []*'

Tags: regex, string, powershell, wildcard

I'm trying to check if a text file contains a certain strings. All my strings are stored in a variable and I check the file the following way

```
ForEach ($word in ($words.split("|"))) {
  if ($word -ne "" -and $word -ne $null) {
    if ($textFile.toLower() -like '*'+$word.toLower()+'*') {
      $contains = $true
    }
  }
}
```

(Words is  a string with different strings, with a | to seperate them).

This works perfectly, unless my string has [] in it. When my strings has [] in it, I will get the following error:
(Example of words: **Warnings: []|Errors: []|Failed to process path:|FilesWithError: 0|VerboseErrors:**  < It will go wrong on the first two words).

```
The specified wildcard pattern is not valid: *warnings: []*
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer to see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400035/powershell-match-strings-stored-in-variables

Comment: Got it working after a while. God I hate regex stuff.

Comment: If you managed to get it working it would be great if you could post your solution below.

Comment: Like Alex said, I escaped the [] characters from my variable.
I Used `[`], works perfect for me.

Comment: @stmfunk I have added a way for escaping the metacharacters in my anwser: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20856324/363573.

Comment: @Jente, in your comment you wrote `[`]. For clarity did you mean you used ``warnings: `[`] ``? (Using doubled backquotes lets you include code with single backquotes in it, but it still doesn't like it unless there are some letters or something).

Comment: Yes, you are right @Duncan. Sometimes, it's still giving problems. I Don't have my code on me atm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the metacharacters from the `$word` variable.

Here is a way to do it:

```
[Regex]::escape($word.toLower()).replace(']','\]')
```

I must call `replace` because the characters escaped by the static method `[Regex]::escape` is so minimal that doesn't include `]`. Without this little help, the final regex would be invalid.

**NOTE:** I have tested this code on **Powershell 2.0**.

Comment: Did you test it without your extra `replace`? The reason `[Regex]::Escape` doesn't escape the closing square bracket is that it doesn't need to be escaped. `]` only has special meaning to close a character class, outside any character class it can be used unescaped.

Comment: @Duncan My first try was without the extra `replace`. I get the following error message `The specified wildcard pattern is not valid: *warnings: \[]*`. I don't know why the closing bracket is treated as a metacharacter.

Comment: Ah, probably because it's a wildcard pattern rather than a regex. It is probably useful to remember that the regex Escape doesn't do the right thing for wildcard patterns. Thanks for that.

Comment: One problem here: the escape character for wildcard patterns is back-quote, not backslash. `"I like warnings: [] and stuff" -like '*warnings: \[\]*'` -> `False`; ``"I like warnings: [] and stuff" -like '*warnings: `[`]*'`` -> `True`. So I still don't understand why it worked when you tested it (maybe it's a Powershell 2.0 versus 3.0 difference).